# SQL select records corresponding to max of dates for last month

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table in a relational DB that looks like this ...

[image]

for every `date` there are multiple `date_created`,i.e my ETL script runs multiple times which records the state of the system on the `date` field and the time ETL ran on the `date_created` field.

EX: on 28/06/22 for item a , ETL ran on 28th and 29th June and recorded values 69 and 70 respectively

Hence, we have to select the data corresponding to max(date_created) for every max(date1) to get the most recent information.

Note: For every item, `max(date)` can be different.

Here is what I've done to get data corresponding to `max(date)` and `max(date_created)`:

```
SELECT      
            fa.item,
            fa.value
FROM 
(SELECT m1.item,  m1.max_date, m2.max_created_date from 
            (SELECT  item,
                    max(date) AS max_date
            FROM myTable
            GROUP BY  1) as m1
LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT item, 
                    date ,
                    max(date_created) as max_created_date 
            FROM myTable group by 1,2) AS m2
ON m1.item = m2.item AND m1.max_date = m2.date) AS mdv

LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
     FROM myTable ) AS fa
ON fa.item = mdv.item
AND fa.date = mdv.max_date
AND fa.date_created = mdv.max_created_date;
```

Given that we are now taking the most recent data, Now I want the most recent data for last month.

For example, if today's date is 29/6/2021.

for item "a", the last available `date` of the last month is 30/05/22 and the last `date_created` for that available day is 1/06/22.

So the highlighted part of the image needs to be selected by the query. How can I write the query for this?

The following highlighted section will be output.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer to get the desired output is very simple.

```
         select * from 
         mytable fa1
         where 
         (fa1.item,fa1.date_created) in (
         Select fa.item,max(date_created)
         from mytable fa
         group by  fa.item )
```